# Why might Java code run fine manually, but not from a Shell Script?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, permissions, scripts

Hi have a frustrating problem: On my Ubuntu 22.04 machine, I have some Java/Maven code which I can run manually from the command line:

```
me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me/path/to/Java/Code$
me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me/path/to/Java/Code$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< MyCode.java >--------------------
...code runs fine...
```

This is great, but I need to run this same code from a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running the script!"
cd /home/me/path/to/Java/Code
mvn test
echo "Script finished."
```

What's weird is that the script can launch the Java code, but the script-run code throws an exception:

```
me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me$
me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me$ ./runScript.sh
Running the script!
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< MyCode.java >--------------------
2022-03-02 12:29:44,899 main ERROR Unable to access file:/home/me/path/to/Java/Code/src/test/resources/log4j2.xml java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/me/path/to/Java/Code/src/test/resources/log4j2.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:157)
    ...etc...
```

This is superweird, right?  When run through the shell script, the Java code suddenly can't access  a "log4j2.xml" file.  ("No such file or directory")  But the file is there, in place, and the code has no issues opening it when I run the code manually.

So what is different when I run the code manually?  I've racked my brains trying to think of what could be different.  I've done all of the following:

- Verified that user `me` manually runs the code from a bash shell, just like the script does.
- Run the script as user `me`, the same user who can run the code manually
- Verified that the script runs as `me` by adding a `whoami` command in the script to check
- Used a `pwd` command to verify that the script run the code from the correct directory.
- Set the script's PATH variable to be the exact same Path as user `me` using the command `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:...` in the script
- Used the visudo command to ensure that user `me` has unlimited access to all files on the Ubuntu
- Made sure the user `me` owns the script and has execute rights
- Yelled and swore at the Ubuntu a lot

What else could the problem be?  I didn't write the Java code, so maybe the code itself refers to this `log4j2.xml` file by relative paths, not absolute paths...?  But if that's the case, why does the code work when manually run?

I know this is an open-ended question, but what else might be different between the script- and the human-initiated versions of running this code.  I've gotta be missing something...

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Don't forget *jammy* is still in *alpha*

Comment: @guiverc Thanks Guiverc!  You think this could be a bug?  >gulp<  Man, I hope not...

Comment: I don't know; I only scanned your text once I saw it was off-topic; however issues with Ubuntu-next (Ubuntu+1) are done on certain sites, which allow testing for issues to be confirmed, bugs filed so they can get fixed - this is not a Ubuntu+1/Ubuntu-Next site ; this site only supports *standard* products, ie. released and not ESM/EOL, nor *development*.

Comment: *one* possibility is that `mvn` is aliased to something in your interactive shell (aliases aren't expanded inside scripts, by default)

Comment: Check output of `find "$HOME" -type f -name 'log4j2.xml'` to see if your paths are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there may be a problem with the path you are `cd`'ing to in the script.

Looking at your command prompt when `mvn test` worked:

> `me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me/path/to/Java/Code$ mvn test`

The leading `~` indicates `$HOME` precedes the displayed path, which would mean the full path is actually `/home/me/home/me/path/to/Java/Code`. This is not the same location as `/home/me/path/to/Java/Code` in your script.